# How to prevent window from becoming disabled when losing focus

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter, replace, tcl

[image]

I've recently recreated some classic Windows search functionality that comes with software like Notepad.

I'm working with Python and Tkinter. I'm missing one last detail. It seems searching a document in Windows Notepad keeps the user prompting dialog permanently enabled. It never gets disabled when focus passes to the main window where the the keywords are getting highlighted. I cannot achieve this in my current experiment. When focus leaves the search dialog it looks "disabled" as expected, until the user clicks on it again. It otherwise works like a charm.

I just wanted to ask, if there's a routine for overriding this default window behaviour, so my search can work like other windows searches. In other words, how to prevent a dialog window from showing it is disabled, during it's lifetime. How to keep it looking "permanently" enabled. How to override this behaviour for a specific dialog window. It can then be perceived by the user as never losing focus. Always available. You think it's possible to achieve this "effect" using Tkinter and TCL?

Comment: Try creating your own dialog with a `Toplevel`

Comment: I don't think *override the disabled-like state* is supported for a toplevel.  You can trying using *floating frame* (a frame using `place()` as layout manager) instead.

Comment: Maybe I'm with Brian Oakley on this one. Perhaps my own dialog can override it's <FocusOut> event and return a "break"?

Comment: I'd actually love to get a solution for this. This kind of functionality is only possible by using a Toplevel window. It has to lose focus for things to work (highlight on Text widget behind it becomes visible) But it does lose focus. Only overriding the FocusOut event could create the desired effect. It needs to continue looking enabled.

Comment: Focus management between windows can be tricky; there are a number of very-ill-documented rules about what works (enforced by the window manager, the Windows shell in your case).